# Monotone convergence theorem (almost everywhere concept)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Could someone enlighten me. Monotone convergence theorem says: if $f_{n},f\in L^{+}$ i.e measurable functions, such that $f_{n}\uparrow f$ pointwise then $\int f_{n}\uparrow \int f$.

But then my teacher says we can relax the condition, using almost everywhere.

We can assume that $f_{n}\uparrow f$ a.e $\Rightarrow \int f_{n}\uparrow \int f$ and then he does something I don't get.

He asks the question:

''Is it true $f_{n}\to f$ a.e $\Rightarrow \int f_{n}\to \int f$?''

what does the horizontal arrow mean in this case? (does he also mean converge to but almost everywhere?)

Here is his counterexample 
$(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L},m)$ and we let $f_{n}=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$

then $\int \chi_{[n,n+1]}dm=m([n,n+1])=1$ but $f_{n}\to 0$ pointwise

Is the horizontal and the vertical arrow meaning the same (''converge to'')?

Why do the characteristic functions converge pointwise??

Comment: "what does the horizontal arrow mean in this case" Pointwise convergence (almost everywhere) without monotonicity assumption. The vertical arrow means the sequence is monotonically nondecreasing (almost everywhere).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, for the "almost-everywhere" MCT:

Suppose that $f_n,\ f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are such that $f_n\nearrow f$ a.e., where $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space.

This means that there is a measureable set $E\subseteq X$ such that $\mu(E)=0$, and we have that $f_n(x)\nearrow f(x)$ for all $x\in X\setminus E$.

If we define new functions $g_n,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$
g_n(x)=\begin{cases}f_n(x) & \text{if }x\notin E\\0 & \text{if }x\in E\end{cases},\qquad g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x) & \text{if }x\notin E\\0 & \text{if }x\in E\end{cases}.
$$
Why should we care about these functions? You can prove:

1. $\int g_n\,d\mu=\int f_n\,d\mu$ for all $n$, since these functions differ on a set of measure $0$; similarly, $\int g\,d\mu=\int f\,d\mu$.
2. For **every** $x\in X$ (not just $x\in E$), $g_n(x)\nearrow g(x)$. Thus, by the MCT, $\int g_n\,d\mu\rightarrow\int g\,d\mu$.

Combining these, we see that $\int f_n\,d\mu\rightarrow\int f\,d\mu$, even though we relaxed our monotonicity assumption a bit.

Now, for his counterexample if we *completely* remove the monotonicity condition: here we have $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$.

You asked why $f_n$ converges pointwise?  Pick any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Note that if we let $n\rightarrow\infty$, then *eventually* $n>x$; but if $n>x$, then $\chi_{[n,n+1]}(x)=0$. This holds for all $n>x$, so that $\chi_{[n,n+1]}(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

This holds for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$; so, the sequence $\{\chi_{[n,n+1]}\}$ converges pointwise to the $0$-function.

This stands in contrast to the fact that, as your instructor said, $\int\chi_{[n,n+1]}\,d\mu=\mu([n,n+1])=1$ when we take $\mu$ to be Lebesgue measure.

Why does this not violate the MCT?  Because the sequence isn't monotone increasing!  Take, for instance, the fact that $\chi_{[1,2]}(1.5)=1$, but $\chi_{[2,3]}(1.5)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much Nicholas, this was a truly exhaustive answer. Helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The hypotheses can be weakened to being positive almost everywhere, increasing in $n$ almost everywhere, and converging pointwise almost everywhere, by replacing $f_n$, $f$ by 0 at points where either positivity, monoticity or pointwise convergence fails and using the results that the integrals of functions that agree a.e. are equal. I can explain more if you like.

In your example it's not increasing anywhere in $n$, which is why the MCT fails.

Comment: thank you, it is easier to deal with these concepts now