# Relation in Almost Surely and Point-wise Convergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I came across two probability and measure textbooks in the context of monotone convergence theorem of measurable functions in $L^1$.

In one textbook, the conditional says $X_n\rightarrow X$ point-wise.

In another, it says $X_n\rightarrow X$.

Please help me understand and verify below:

My understanding of point-wise and almost surely are distinct convergence concepts that are more like apples and oranges. One involves a measure, the other one deals with a convergence of reals, for example if the sequence of measurable functions is random variables.

(1) So is one of the textbooks incorrect?

(2) Is my understanding of how to compare and NOT to compare these convergence concepts correct?

Comment: In probability theory (and in measure theory in general), you rarely care about pointwise convergence, only convergence on a set whose complement has measure zero. In the case of a probability measure, this means convergence on a set with probability one, i.e. almost sure convergence.

Comment: @Math1000 You are absolutely right, so point-wise convergence is the analogous of point-wise in measure theoretic settings, right?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499795/monotone-convergence-theorem-almost-everywhere-concept